# Identify store catchments with a range limit

Tags: r, matrix, nearest-neighbor

I have an example here of two houses and five stores. Each store has a limit in how far it is willing to deliver to (a catchment). I would like to know, for each house, how many stores will deliver to the house. Here is an example (in reality I have 1m houses and 17k stores).

```
library(FNN)

xh <- c(3,8)
yh <- c(8,2) 
house.df <- data.frame(cbind(xh,yh))

xs <- c(3,3,5,8,8)
ys <- c(3,6,8,9,4)
catchment <- c(3,3,4,6,3)
store.df <- data.frame(cbind(xs,ys,catchment))

plot(house.df$xh,house.df$yh,pch=16,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(store.df$xs,store.df$ys,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10))

nndist <- knnx.dist(store.df[,c("xs","ys")],house.df[,c("xh","yh")], k=4)
nnindex <- knnx.index(store.df[,c("xs","ys")],house.df[,c("xh","yh")], k=4)

nndist
     [,1]    [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,]    2 2.00000 5.000000 5.099020
[2,]    2 5.09902 6.403124 6.708204

nnindex
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    2    1    4
[2,]    5    1    2    3
```

Here I have just asked for the 4 (of the 5 nearest stores). House 1 can be served by stores 3, 2, and 4 because it is in their catchment but not store 3 which has a catchment limit of 3. House 2 can only be served by store 5, all the other distances are outside stores 1, 2 and 3's catchment. In the end what I'd like is:

```
nnserve
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    2   NA    4
[2,]    5   NA   NA   NA
```

If all stores has the same catchment I could simply use:

```
# distances greater than 3 ignore
nndist[nndist>3]<-NA
```

What I have been trying to do is replicate nnindex but have the catchment of the stores as the entries:

```
nncatchment
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    3    3    6
[2,]    3    3    3    4
```

and then do an element by element comparison of nndist and nncatchment, but don't know how to make nncatchment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer (with help from a colleague)

```
nnserve <- (matrix(store.df$catchment[nnindex],nrow=nrow(nndist),ncol=ncol(nndist),byrow=FALSE)>nndist)
apply(nnserve, MARGIN = 1, function(x) sum(x))
```